# Better Design to access XmlBeanFactory with Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to find a better what to do this.  In Spring a  lot of my classes need to load beans (objects) from XmlBeanFactory. So I put the following line into most of my classes

```
private static XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(
            new ClassPathResource("config.xml"));
```

Does anyone know of a better what for me to do this so I don't have to have this in most of my classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your class implement [BeanFactoryAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryAware.html) that will give you instance of the bean factory, so you could call one of [BeanFactory.getBean(..)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean%28java.lang.String%29) methods directly.

```
public class MyFactoryBean implements BeanFactoryAware {
  private BeanFactory beanFactory;

  public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
  }

  public void someMethod() {
    MyBean myBean = beanFactory.getBean("myBean", MyBean.class);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can u post a example on how to do that

Comment: Can't believe you've made me type it here. You definitely have to accept the answer now. :)

Comment: I added implements BeanFactoryAware to my object now I get a null pointed?

Comment: Naturally, the instance of MyFactoryBean should be obtained from the Spring context.

Comment: thanks.. I did not know that and learned it just now.. thanks!